# Dealing with deprecated android.text.ClipboardManager

Tags: java, android, clipboard

`android.text.ClipboardManager` was deprecated since API level 11, and replaced with `android.content.ClipboardManager` ([source](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/ClipboardManager.html)).

How do I write code that supports both cases? Importing `android.content.ClipboardManager` and using that works in 11+ but force closes in 10. Changing the import to `android.text.ClipboardManager` throws a bunch of deprecation warnings in 11+.

How can I handle both cases smoothly? What do I need to import?

Answer (score 6):

Referring to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14189589/4665578):

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
final android.content.ClipboardManager clipboardManager = (android.content.ClipboardManager) context
        .getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
final android.content.ClipData clipData = android.content.ClipData
        .newPlainText("text label", "text to clip");
clipboardManager.setPrimaryClip(clipData);
} else {
final android.text.ClipboardManager clipboardManager = (android.text.ClipboardManager) context
        .getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
clipboardManager.setText("text to clip");
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Explicitly:

```
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    android.text.ClipboardManager clipboard = (android.text.ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
    clipboard.setText(shareViaSMSBody);
```

Since this has to keep working on older devices, it is likely that the deprecated code will not be removed from Android.

Answer (score 1):

If you are still supporting < SDK 11 you are doing too much work.  Set min to 15 and use this code:

```
 ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE); 
 ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("label for text", "text to copy");
 clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
```

Comment: well, my gf use an old kindle so sdk 15 is not a choice

Answer (score 0):

Reading the latest clipboard as text:

```
val clipboardManager = context.getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE) as ClipboardManager
clipboardManager.addPrimaryClipChangedListener {
    val clipboardAsText = clipboardManager.primaryClip?.getItemAt(0)?.text
    if (clipboardAsText != null) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Text in clipboard: $clipboardAsText", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Updated code in kotlin without deprecated method.**

Here my import :

```
import android.content.ClipboardManager
import android.content.Context
import android.content.ClipData
```

My text/button click

```
 bind.txtMail.setOnClickListener {
        copyToClipboard()
 }
```

Here is the fix **bind.txtMail.context.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE) as ClipboardManager**

```
private fun copyToClipboard() {
    val t = bind.txtMail.text.toString()
    val clipboardManager =
        bind.txtMail.context.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE) as ClipboardManager
    val clipData = ClipData.newPlainText(null, t)
    clipboardManager.setPrimaryClip(clipData)

    Toast.makeText(requireContext(), t, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```