# Declare a variable inside an if statement and have it known to following method calls

Tags: java, android, clipboardmanager

I'm writing something in Android and in order to tailor for an older SDK, I need to change what a variable becomes. I'm using `ClipboardManager` which has different versions based on SDK. The issue is to create this variable easily, I have to do it in an if, and my code won't compile after due to the variable not being detected.

Example:

```
if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11){
    final android.content.ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
} else {
    final android.text.ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
}
if (clipboard.hasPrimaryClip()) {
    // Do stuff
}
```

Because the instance of clipboard depends on the SDK, `if (clipboard.hasPrimaryClip())` complains at me.

Is there any way to do this other than making two variables and checking for null?

Comment: I'm not an Android expert, but based on the documentation I found, `android.text.ClipboardManager` doesn't have a `hasPrimaryClip` method.  So if the version is < 11, then what were you expecting `clipboard.hasPrimaryClip()` to do?

Comment: @ajb You're right, it'd be `getText()` for the older API but it was just for example.

Comment: Well, if you'll have to call a differently named method for the two different branches of the `if`...`else`, then I don't see how you thought you could do the method call outside the `if`.  However, if you were going to call some method that **does** exist in both, you could declare it to be `android.text.ClipboardManager` (outside the `if`), because the variable would still be able to hold an `android.content.ClipboardManager` since it's a subclass.

Comment: Ok I'll replace it. The point is that was an example, I didn't think about that method being that API+ only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare it as a class member

```
ClipboardManager clipboard;
```

Then

```
if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11){
clipboard = (ClipboardManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
}else {
 clipboard = (ClipboardManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
}
 if (clipboard.hasPrimaryClip()) {
// Do stuff
}
```

Eidt to the edited question

```
   if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11){
     final android.content.ClipboardManager clipboard =  (ClipboardManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
       if (clipboard.hasPrimaryClip()) {
        // Do stuff
        doSomething(); 
       }
   } else {
     final android.text.ClipboardManager clipboard =(ClipboardManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
      if (clipboard.hasPrimaryClip()) {
        // Do stuff
        doSomething(); 
       }
   }
```

Then

```
 public void doSomething()
 {

 }
```

Comment: Ok, I realised my question wasn't clear because of this answer. Let me edit it.

Comment: @Zackehh9lives if i understand correctly you need to declare the variable with class scope so it is available through out the class. no need for two variables.

Comment: It's my bad, I didn't show that ClipboardManager is imported from different packages each time. Check updated question.

Comment: But how do I override the fact that I declared Clipboard to be an instance of a different class?

Comment: @Zackehh9lives in that case you need to have two variables and chekc your condition in both if part and else part

Comment: @Zackehh9lives if the condition is true you intend do dosomething similar for both the cases?

Comment: Yes, same thing for both - but if moving the stuff to do into the if is better I'll do it that way. I didn't really think it'd be doable.

Comment: @Zackehh9lives check `if (clipboard.hasPrimaryClip())` in both if and else then call a method `dosomething` so if any condition satisfies it calls dosomething which is common in both cases.

Comment: @Zackehh9lives http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14189544/copy-with-clipboard-manager-that-supports-old-and-new-android-versions.

Comment: Yeah that's the way I'm doing it now, too bad it couldn't just be those few lines :p

Comment: FYI, based on the doc I found, `android.content.ClipboardManager` is a direct subclass of `android.text.ClipboardManager`.  So if the latter had a `hasPrimaryClip()` method that was overridden in the subclass, it would be simple to have him declare the variable as `android.text.ClipboardManager`.  However, `android.text.ClipboardManager` doesn't have a `hasPrimaryClip` method at all, so there's a lot more confusion here than initially appears.

Comment: ok then just dosomething on inside the if else with out checking the condition. so if less then 11 do something else dosomething. the idea however is the same.