# Click button so it would be coppeid

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, copy

### How can I click on a button (phone number) and it copies it and show me that it was copied?

activity_main.xml

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/phonenumberhotel"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:text="Tel.: 00000 0 000 0000"/>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.iss.dfdfd;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager.NameNotFoundException;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.ClipboardManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class PageOneHotel extends Activity {


    Button phonenumberhotel;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.hotel);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Phone number has been copied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        addButtonListener();
        addListenerOnButton();

    }


    public void addListenerOnButton() {

        phonenumberhotel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.phonenumberhotel);

        phonenumberhotel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO add action here
            }
        });
        ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE); 
        ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("label", "Copied");


    }
}
```

I did that, the number is not copied, only a msg appears from the toast .. I just want to click on the button and it tells me the number is copied. When I go to the dialer, it pastes nothing .. help :)

Comment: mm more explanation plz, your attempts, etc?!  :\

Comment: I hope it's explained with the other post, I'll post something in a bit

Comment: Or no need, @eldest explained it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

public class PageOneHotel extends Activity {

```
final Button phonenumberhotel;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.hotel);
    addButtonListener();
    addListenerOnButton();

}


public void addListenerOnButton() {

    phonenumberhotel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.phonenumberhotel);

    phonenumberhotel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
             String number = phonenumberhotel.getText().toString()
             ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("Phone number",number);   
             clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
             Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Phone number has been copied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });


}
```

}

Comment: thank you, if you come first with the solution I can mark you :/

Comment: You are almost there. I edited my answer to match your updated question. If this solves your problem please mark it as accepted :)

Comment: Hello MrJm
It gives me another two errors :/ .. http://oi57.tinypic.com/flf3u0.jpg

Comment: Hello, there is indeed an error. getText needs to be getText() so you will get String number = phonenumberhotel.getText().toString();
For the clipboard.setPrimaryClip make sure you have the right imports 
import android.content.ClipData;
import android.content.ClipboardManager;

Comment: I have an error again but the first one is done .. the error is with the clipboard.setPrimaryClip .. also you explained it but it doest work http://oi61.tinypic.com/2w68g0o.jpg .. I added these import though, they add themselves automatically .. http://oi57.tinypic.com/2rqisgi.jpg ... help? :)

Comment: You still have an old import for ClipboardManager. If you remove 
import android.text.ClipboardManager; you will be fine ;) If not, can you show the error message you are getting?

Comment: Hello MrJm .. I tried it but it didn't copy as in http://oi59.tinypic.com/vql8hw.jpg .. I removed "clip" with warning but it didn't copy as in http://oi61.tinypic.com/s2uzkk.jpg ..I removed "clipboard" with warning but it didn't copy as in http://oi59.tinypic.com/24b2fcx.jpg .. I removed "number" with warning but it didn't copy as in http://oi58.tinypic.com/2qco4m0.jpg .. it looks like this http://oi59.tinypic.com/2wlqz4j.jpg .. no warnings .. no errors :/

Comment: You don't need to make changes to your method. This works as it should. What you did is remove the copy functionality, this is why it's not working. All you have to do is fix the imports on top of your class. Change this line: "import android.text.ClipboardManager;" to " import android.content.ClipboardManager;"

Comment: Thank you, I fixed it, it created two java files "ClipData" and "ClipboardManager" .. so the application worked and gave me no error but when I run on my mobile, it gives me an error when I tick to copy :/

Comment: p.s. I am using Android 2.2

Answer (score 2):

Here is the fragment of code which copies text to clipboard in Android: [How to copy text programmatically in my Android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238284/how-to-copy-text-programmatically-in-my-android-app)

When creating your button add `.setOnClickListener()` with your own listener which in his method `onClick()` calls given fragment of code.

Text of Button can be obtained via `button.getText().toString()`

Comment: I'm using Android 2.2 and the click on a button only :/

Comment: so, use this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14189544/copy-with-clipboard-manager-that-supports-old-and-new-android-versions

Comment: You're welcome :), if this helped, please mark answer as correct so others can find it quickly.