# cut copy paste on Textview in android

Tags: android, clipboard

I want to enable cut, copy and paste features on textviews in my app.
I have scene the below link also to implement it but it also do not work.

[Copy with clipboard manager that supports old and new android versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14189544/copy-with-clipboard-manager-that-supports-old-and-new-android-versions/14189589#14189589)

Please provide me a solution which can work.

Thanks a lot in advanced.

Comment: The text is get copying but the clipboard bar is not displayed when I LongClick on Textview. I want to display that also.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I enable standard copy paste for a TextView in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10386084/how-do-i-enable-standard-copy-paste-for-a-textview-in-android)

Answer (score 2):

In your xml layout add

```
android:textIsSelectable="true"
```

Or In java

```
myTextView.setTextIsSelectable(true);
```