# Copy Text of a Text Field

Tags: android, eclipse, copy, textfield

I have a Text Field and a Button. I'd make it so as soon as the button is pressed the text of the Text Field to be copied. How can this be done? As I search it ([How to copy text programmatically in my Android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238284/how-to-copy-text-programmatically-in-my-android-app)), I read about a ClipboardManager method but rumours say it is also deprecated. Should I avoid it? Thanks

Comment: Refer this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8056838/dealing-with-deprecated-android-text-clipboardmanager)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honeycomb deprecated `android.text.ClipboardManager` and introduced `android.content.ClipboardManager`.

You should check whether `android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` is at least `android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB` and therefore use one or the other.

```
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    {
        // Old clibpoard
        android.text.ClipboardManager clipboard = (android.text.ClipboardManager)getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        clipboard.setText("the text");
    } 
    else
    {
        android.content.ClipboardManager clipboard = (android.content.ClipboardManager)getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        android.content.ClipData clipData = android.content.ClipData.newPlainText("PlainText", "the text");
        clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clipData);
    }
```

Comment: This answer is very much similar to my answer @matiash ..kindly check other answers too before posting new answers..

Comment: I answered a shorter version, then added the code afterwards. Sorry.

Comment: Its ok @matiash ..I just pointed out..No need for sry and all..any way i'l upvote your answer too..

Answer (score 1):

Try the answer in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14189544/copy-with-clipboard-manager-that-supports-old-and-new-android-versions)..It says

```
 int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
            if(sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                android.text.ClipboardManager clipboard = (android.text.ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                clipboard.setText("text to clip");
            } else {
                android.content.ClipboardManager clipboard = (android.content.ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE); 
                android.content.ClipData clip = android.content.ClipData.newPlainText("text label","text to clip");
                clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

[Copy/Paste Offical Tutoiral](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/copy-paste.html)
Check it out

Relative Code :

```
ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager)
    getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
Copy the data to a new ClipData object:
For text

// Creates a new text clip to put on the clipboard
 ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("simple text","Hello, World!");
```

Comment: Please include relevant information from the link you provided.